# How do you past values between classes in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

How do you past values between classes in objective-c?

Comment: Function calls?  You need to give us more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to assume the question involves a class, `ClassOne`, with an instance variable `int integerOne`, which you'd like to access from another class, `ClassTwo`. The best way to handle this is to create a property in `ClassOne`. In ClassOne.h:

```
@property (assign) int integerOne;
```

This declares a property (basically, two methods, `- (int)integerOne`, and `- (void)setIntegerOne:(int)newInteger`). Then, in ClassOne.m:

```
@synthesize integerOne;
```

This "synthesizes" the two methods for you. This is basically equivalent to:

```
- (int)integerOne
{
    return integerOne;
}

- (void)setIntegerOne:(int)newInteger
{
    integerOne = newInteger;
}
```

At this point, you can now call these methods from `ClassTwo`. In ClassTwo.m:

```
#import "ClassOne.h"
//Importing ClassOne.h will tell the compiler about the methods you declared, preventing warnings at compilation

- (void)someMethodRequiringTheInteger
{
    //First, we'll create an example ClassOne instance
    ClassOne* exampleObject = [[ClassOne alloc] init];

    //Now, using our newly written property, we can access integerOne.
    NSLog(@"Here's integerOne: %i",[exampleObject integerOne]);

    //We can even change it.
    [exampleObject setIntegerOne:5];
    NSLog(@"Here's our changed value: %i",[exampleObject integerOne]);
}
```

It sounds like you should walk through a few tutorials to learn these Objective-C concepts. I suggest [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362476/whats-the-best-resource-to-learn-how-to-write-apps-for-mac-os-x/1362595#1362595).