# OSX dektop development framework

Tags: macos, frameworks, desktop-application

So I've been dabbling around in the Appcelerator Titanium framework for the better part of a week or two and find it intriguing how easy it is to make "native" iphone apps with it, and on the plus-side, with the help of the wonderful javascript language.

I find the desktop framework lacking in functionality though and would like to be able to create more native-looking desktop applications. So to my question.

What options do I have for making OSX desktop apps (without learning obj-c that is )? I have the following "requirements".

- MUST be able to submit to the Mac App Store.
- Not done in Obj-c.
- Preferably with some sort of GUI builder.
- GUI components should look as native as possible.
- The cost for a license should be as low as possible.
- No real need for cross-platform, though it would be considered a plus.

I have checked the following frameworks:

- [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com/)

  - Though i'm not too happy about using Basic, I have prior knowledge in it. This looks like my best bet so far.
- [Mac Ruby](http://www.macruby.org)

  - Need to learn Ruby first, not necessarily a deal breaker though.
- [MonoMac](http://www.mono-project.com/MonoMac)

  - I guess C# is close to Java, which I know more or less by heart.
- [Appcelerator Titanium](http://www.appcelerator.com)

  - Love the fact that it is javacript, to much hassle to do the gui though. Maybe I should just brush up on my html and css for this. I do love javascript.

Comment: Have you looked at [XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Getting_started_with_XULRunner)? XUL is the language/platform that Mozilla uses to code Thunderbird and Firefox. It is similar to Appcelerator Titanium, I think, but completely free and OSS. BTW, like Firefox, you can also run your application on Linux and Windows with little trouble.

Comment: Why are you willing to learn Basic, Ruby, C#, HTML, and CSS, but not Objective-C, the actual native language? Which, I might add, would allow you to use Interface Builder, submit to the Mac App Store, give 100% native GUI components, have no license cost, and possibly even be cross-platform via Cocotron?

Comment: I already know Basic, HTML, CSS and some C#, just need to brush up on them a bit, which will be no biggie. I have contemplated learning Objective-C, so it's not completely out of the picture, though I would prefer something that I already have some basic skills in and therefore can be up and running in shorter time than Objective-c

Comment: You're going to have to brush up anyway, and you'll need to learn a GUI builder. Take the extra starting time to learn the native language and you'll gain that time back a hundred times over later in development. I honestly think you can be up and running with Obj-C quicker than you expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1362476/whats-the-best-resource-to-learn-how-to-write-apps-for-mac-os-x/1362595#1362595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually went with a hybrid-approach:

I started out using Appcelerator Titanium for the first version.

For the next version I added stuff into the framework (since it's [open source](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_desktop)), like making "real" dialogs with custom buttons and such, and loading nib files with gui as dialogs and also some filesystem additions.

In hindsight I just wish I went all-out obj-c like andyvn22 recommended me to do, since I've learnt quite a bit about it now. The next "major" version might be a objective-c rewrite.

Comment: Have you considered using the framework that apps like tweetbot, and twitter client use? Essentially it's an Xcode project you download, and you can write HTML/CSS for most of the stuff. You'll need to do a little bit of Objective C to make buttons work and open windows, but it would be a lot less than writing an app from scratch, since all the views are just webkit local html pages…